# Wiring button cell without soldering using household material?

Tags: led, wiring

I bought some hearing aid button cells for pennies. I want to use them in a toy project that connects a push button switch and an LED. I hook up the LED and switch using alligator clips without problem. But I am running into trouble keeping the small button cell from disconnecting. I can't use alligator clip because it shorts easily. Any ideas how I can keep connected?

Comment: do the cells provide enough current to light an LED?

Comment: I need to connect 2 of them in serial

Comment: Magnet. Coin cell holder.

Comment: Just tried magnet. It seems magnet only attracts to the +ve (the flat) side. It is kind of unstable.

Answer (score 2):

Use a wood or plastic spring clothespin, or other non-conducting spring clip, to hold the wires against the two sides of the cell.

Comment: A small "binder clip" or "bulldog clip", with insulating tape on the jaws, might be stronger.

Comment: Tried both. It is difficult as the hearing aid cell is too damn small. It is hard to keep it place without slipping. I guess I need to use tape.

Comment: Or find a tube which they fit into, use that to help hold them together.  Or tape around the edge.

Answer (score 1):

Stretchy tape should work well. Use electrical tape or elastic bandage tape. If you bend the LED leads as shown below, you the positive lead can serve as the switch. The cells shown are probably at least twice as large as hearing-aid batteries, but the method shown should still work.

[image]

Comment: I did something very similar, just that I bent the legs of the LED with needle-nose pliers: One of them  into a flat spiral, making a "contact plate" of sorts, the other as a slightly helical/conical spring "aimed" at the plate, thereby building a spring-loaded connector. Worked well enough for the flatter coin cell types to work without tape; was a nice stocking stuffer for my father to have something to play around with. (had 10 unused coin cells from chinese throwaway electronics, and no better use, as well as a matching amount of LEDs)